# Binding to a selected object's observable collection list?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have two `DataGrid`s defined in the xaml.  The first is bound to one `ObservableCollection`.  I want to somehow bind the second `DataGrid` to an `ObservableCollection` property on the selected object in the first `DataGrid`.  Is there simple binding syntax for this, or do I have to do a whole lot of extra stuff in the code behind on some select event?

Answer (score 1):

Go MVVM way:

1. Take your `ObservableCollection` in `ViewModel` say `ObservableCollection<T1>` where T1 is the class which already contains your second collection say `ObservableCollection<T2>`
2. Bind this `ObservableCollection<T1>` with the `DataSource` property of first `DataGrid`.
3. Take a property `SelectedItem` of type T1 in your `ViewModel`.
4. Bind this property's `ObservableCollection<T2>` with the `DataSource` of your second `DataGrid`.

Comment: Right, just that Datasource -> ItemsSource.

Answer (score 1):

@Nitin Joshi is absolutely right. To put those "bullets" in code format, you'd might end up with something like...

**View**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column" Binding="{Binding}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column" Binding="{Binding}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _items;
    private string _selectedItem;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>(new[] { "a", "b", "c" });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set { _selectedItem = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image: imgur]

---

**Edit:**

If you don't want to use `ViewModelBase` from `MVVMLight` (available via NuGet), you can achieve same functionality implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface yourself. Then above would be become:

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    // Same code as above, notice different base class
}
```

Where `BaseViewModel` is

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) 
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `ViewModelBase` something you implemented?  Or is that in some other dll I don't have referenced in the standard wpf project?

Comment: It's part of `MVVMLight` which makes MVVM implementation that much easier. For this, you can achieve needed functionality by implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the (base) ViewModel.

Comment: Edited my answer to include how you would achieve same thing w/o MVVMLight.